# how to modify value of property has unique key in ef6

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core-mvc

When i update value of specify product, i cannot update product.name because it has unique contain

```
 builder.HasAlternateKey(x => x.Name);
```

when I call `_context.SaveChange();` it cause this error message :"
The property 'Product.Name' is part of a key and so cannot be modified or marked as modified. To change the principal of an existing entity with an identifying foreign key, first delete the dependent and invoke 'SaveChanges', and then associate the dependent with the new principal"

how can I update productName field ? I leave my update code below:

```
try
            {
                var product = await _context.Products.FindAsync(request.Id);


                if (product == null) throw new ProjectException($"Cannot find a product with id: {request.Id}");

                product.Name = request.Name;
                product.Price = request.Price;
                product.Stock = request.Stock;
                product.Description = request.Description;
                product.productStatus = request.productStatus;

                //Save image
                if (request.ThumbnailImage != null)
                {
                    var thumbnailImage = await _context.ProductImages.FirstOrDefaultAsync(i => i.IsDefault == true && i.ProductId == request.Id);
                    if (thumbnailImage != null)
                    {
                        thumbnailImage.FileSize = request.ThumbnailImage.Length;
                        thumbnailImage.ImagePath = await this.SaveFile(request.ThumbnailImage);
                        _context.ProductImages.Update(thumbnailImage);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        product.ProductImages = new List<ProductImage>()
                    {
                        new ProductImage()
                        {
                            Caption = "Thumbnail image",
                            DateCreated = DateTime.Now,
                            FileSize = request.ThumbnailImage.Length,
                            ImagePath = await this.SaveFile(request.ThumbnailImage),
                            IsDefault = true,
                            SortOrder = 1
                        }
                    };
                    }
                }
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                var xx = e.Message;//get message in debuging
                var x = 1;//this line make me have time to read error message :(
                return false;
                
            }
```

Comment: If you just want a unique index, then use the `HasIndex()` method, rather than `AlternateKey()` . Unique index values can be changed. But you cannot change alternate keys

Comment: `builder.Property(x => x.Name).HasMaxLength(length).IsUnique();`